# Compare security groups in Pivotal CRM

Tags: pivotal-crm

I want to see the differences between 2 security groups in Pivotal CRM... is there a way to do this?

I tried doing it in the database on the BM, going via the Groups, Group_* tables and this worked for the Group_Table table, but got too hard with things like Group_Search_Result_List where it goes via Group_Table itself. All I want to know is the differences... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? In version 6 you can export the group to XML and then compare using any text diff tool